# Can't Install Python 2.7.3 on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, python, make

I have a CentOS 6 (minimum install or netinstall, I can't remember which) on a virtual machine. I'm trying to install [Plone 4.2.4](https://launchpad.net/plone/4.2/4.2.4/+download/Plone-4.2.4-UnifiedInstaller-r3.tgz) on it for testing purposes. I have installed all the required dependencies, or at leat I think so.

I run the Plone Unified Installer (I use the `--static-lxml` option because Plone requires a libxml2 version not present on CentOS)

> ./install.sh --static-lxml standalone

I get the following error:

```
Stand-Alone Zope Instance selected

Detailed installation log being written to /root/plone/Plone-4.2.4-UnifiedInstaller/install.log

Root install method chosen. Will install for use by system user plone

Installing Plone 4.2.4 at /usr/local/Plone

User 'plone' already exists. No need to create it.
Skipping libjpeg build
Skipping readline build
Installing Python-2.7.3. This takes a while...
Install of Python-2.7.3 has failed.

Installation has failed.
See the detailed installation log at /root/plone/Plone-4.2.4-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
to determine the cause.
```

[Here's the Plone install log](http://pastebin.com/A7riePU8).

I installed [Pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) to try to install Python 2.73 using it. I can sucessfuly install Pythonbrew, but when I run `pythonbrew install 2.7.3` I get the following error:

```
[test@plonemachine root]$ pythonbrew install 2.7.3
Use the previously fetched /home/test/.pythonbrew/dists/Python-2.7.3.tgz
Extracting Python-2.7.3.tgz into /home/test/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7.3

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:
  tail -f "/home/test/.pythonbrew/log/build.log"

Patching Python-2.7.3
Installing Python-2.7.3 into /home/test/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3
ERROR: Failed to install Python-2.7.3. See /home/test/.pythonbrew/log/build.log to see why.
```

[Here's the Pythonbrew build log.](http://pastebin.com/nL8Vr2XQ) It's almost identical to the Plone install log(!), leading me to believe the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like the configure script exited correctly and the Makefiles were created. My guess is that you are missing some of the basic development tools, perhaps `autoconf`. Try installing them with this command as root ([source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-install-gcc-c-c-compiler/)):

```
 yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```